# Multiple Choice Survey Response With Checkboxes and Textboxes

Tags: survey-list

I've been handed a Word document to turn into a Sharepoint 2010 survey. One of the "vital" questions on the survey is formatted in the following format:

> What device(s) do you use on a daily basis? (Check all that apply, insert % of usage.)
>
> ☐ Desktop __%
>
> ☐ Laptop __%
>
> ☐ Tablet __%
>
> ☐ Mobile Phone __%

There's several questions in this format, many of them with more than 8 options. To make things even more complicated, two of the questions even feature the option:

> ☐ Other ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__** , __%

I'm relatively new to Sharepoint 2010, and haven't been able to figure out how to format a question in this style. Is Sharepoint incapable of doing anything beyond simple multiple-choice checkbox questions?

Comment: Basically, if you want a real survey tool, get something Like Qualtrics or Survey Monkey and expose the survey in your SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint does not have a field type anything like you require OOB. SharePoint is however customisable and extensible. Whilst out of the box it can't do everything (how can one product do everything) it can be customised/extended to do so. In this instance custom field types could be developed with custom rendering controls or maybe easier is to use SharePoint designer to create a custom form. JavaScript could be used to validate required fields but you could then use a few of the native fields of a SharePoint list for one question.

I realise it's not the answer you probably want to hear.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the Survey list cannot do this on its own. However, in the case the simplest solution on SharePoint would be to use an InfoPath form. You have a lot more flexibility with InfoPath forms.